# An exception of type 'System.Runtime.Serialization.SerializationException' occurred in mscorlib.dll

Tags: c#, .net, exception, serialization, botframework

I am trying to add calling feature to my bot using speech to text recognition to my bot using bing speech api.
When I run my application it gives me an exception at the run time (given in the title). I am not sure how to handle it and what is causing it.
It occurs at the following line in SendToBot method.

```
await postToBot.PostAsync(activity, CancellationToken.None);
```

> Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.NullWait`1[[Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask,
>   Microsoft.Bot.Builder, Version=3.5.5.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35]]' in Assembly 'Microsoft.Bot.Builder,
>   Version=3.5.5.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=31bf3856ad364e35' is
>   not marked as serializable.

Stack Trace:

```
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.InternalGetSerializableMembers(RuntimeType type)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.FormatterServices.GetSerializableMembers(Type type, StreamingContext context)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitMemberInfo()
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.WriteObjectInfo.InitSerialize(Object obj, ISurrogateSelector surrogateSelector, StreamingContext context, SerObjectInfoInit serObjectInfoInit, IFormatterConverter converter, ObjectWriter objectWriter, SerializationBinder binder)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Write(WriteObjectInfo objectInfo, NameInfo memberNameInfo, NameInfo typeNameInfo)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.ObjectWriter.Serialize(Object graph, Header[] inHeaders, __BinaryWriter serWriter, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph, Header[] headers, Boolean fCheck)
   at System.Runtime.Serialization.Formatters.Binary.BinaryFormatter.Serialize(Stream serializationStream, Object graph)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.FormatterStore`1.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IStore<T>.Save(T item)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.ErrorResilientStore`1.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IStore<T>.Save(T item)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.FactoryStore`1.Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Internals.Fibers.IStore<T>.Save(T item)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.DialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Base-IEventLoop-PollAsync>d__23.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ReactiveDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Base-IEventLoop-PollAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ScoringEventLoop`1.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Base-IEventLoop-PollAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.EventLoopDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SetAmbientThreadCulture.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PersistentDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.ExceptionTranslationDialogTask.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__2.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.SerializeByConversation.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__4.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUser.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.PostUnhandledExceptionToUser.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__5.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Internals.LogPostToBot.<Microsoft-Bot-Builder-Dialogs-Internals-IPostToBot-PostAsync>d__3.MoveNext()
--- End of stack trace from previous location where exception was thrown ---
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.ThrowForNonSuccess(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.HandleNonSuccessAndDebuggerNotification(Task task)
   at System.Runtime.CompilerServices.TaskAwaiter.GetResult()
   at JoeBot.BingSpeech.<SendToBot>d__14.MoveNext() in D:\PARIS\JoeBot\CallingBot\BingSpeech.cs:line 123
```

In following method in BingSpeech class (given in the end)

```
private async Task SendToBot(RecognizedPhrase recognizedPhrase)
    {
        Activity activity = new Activity()
        {
            From = new ChannelAccount { Id = conversationResult.Id },
            Conversation = new ConversationAccount { Id = conversationResult.Id },
            Recipient = new ChannelAccount { Id = "Bot" },
            ServiceUrl = "https://skype.botframework.com",
            ChannelId = "skype",
        };

        activity.Text = recognizedPhrase.DisplayText;

        using (var scope = Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation
            .Container.BeginLifetimeScope(DialogModule.LifetimeScopeTag, Configure))
        {
            scope.Resolve<IMessageActivity>
                (TypedParameter.From((IMessageActivity)activity));
            DialogModule_MakeRoot.Register
                (scope, () => new LUISDialogClass());
            var postToBot = scope.Resolve<IPostToBot>();
            await postToBot.PostAsync(activity, CancellationToken.None);
        }
    }
```

My LUISDialogClass() is marked as Serializable. LUIS is the root dialog and it forwards request to further WikipediaDialog class based on intent/Entity match. I am also creating JSON string here using static class and fields (for some special purpose/ sending it to a server).

```
[Serializable]
public class LUISDialogClass : LuisDialog<object>
{

    [LuisIntent("")]
    [LuisIntent("None")]
    public async Task None(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        var message =  result;
        await context.PostAsync("Intent match : None");
        context.Wait(MessageReceived);
    }

    [LuisIntent("FindInfo")]
    public async Task FindInfo(IDialogContext context, LuisResult result)
    {
        try
        {
            var message =  result;

            for (int i = 1; i < 2; i++)
            {                    
                JSONDataObjects.data[i] = new Datum();
                JSONDataObjects.data[i].dataKind = "luisResponse";
                JSONDataObjects.data[i].query = message.Query;
                JSONDataObjects.data[i].intents = new Intent[message.Intents.Count];
                JSONDataObjects.data[i].entities = new Entity[message.Entities.Count];
                for (int j = 0; j < message.Intents.Count; j++)
                {
                    JSONDataObjects.data[i].intents[j] = new Intent();
                    JSONDataObjects.data[i].intents[j].intent = message.Intents[j]?.Intent;
                    JSONDataObjects.data[i].intents[j].score = (float)message.Intents[j]?.Score;                        
                }
                for (int j = 0; j < message.Entities.Count; j++)
                {
                    JSONDataObjects.data[i].entities[j] = new Entity();
                    JSONDataObjects.data[i].entities[j].entity = message.Entities[j]?.Entity;
                    JSONDataObjects.data[i].entities[j].type = message.Entities[j]?.Type;
                    JSONDataObjects.data[i].entities[j].startIndex = (int)message.Entities[j]?.StartIndex;
                    JSONDataObjects.data[i].entities[j].endIndex = (int)message.Entities[j]?.EndIndex;
                    JSONDataObjects.data[i].entities[j].score = (float)message.Entities[j]?.Score;
                }
            }

            // See if the intent has a > .70 match
            bool boolIntentMatch = false;
            foreach (var objIntent in message.Intents)
            {
                // If the FindInfo Intent is detected
                // and it's score is greater than or = to .70 
                // set boolIntentMatch = true
                if (
                    (objIntent.Intent == "FindInfo")
                    && (objIntent.Score >= .70f)
                    )
                {
                    boolIntentMatch = true;
                }
            }
            if (boolIntentMatch)
            {
                // ** To Do: Code to handle a Match **

                string item = "";
                EntityRecommendation rec;
                if (message.TryFindEntity("objects", out rec))
                {
                    item = rec.Entity;
                }
                else if (message.TryFindEntity("location", out rec))
                {
                    item = rec.Entity;
                }

                Activity messageActivity = (Activity)context.MakeMessage();
                messageActivity.Text = item;
                messageActivity.ChannelId = "emulator";
                await context.Forward(new WikipediaDialog(), ResumeAfterWikipedia, messageActivity, System.Threading.CancellationToken.None);

            }
            else
            {
                // Not a match -- Ask to rephrase the question
                await context.PostAsync("Please try to rephrase your question. Not a good intent match found");
            }


        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {

            //Debug.WriteLine(ex);
            await context.PostAsync($"Failed and caught in FindInfo LUIS Dialog, with Exception: {ex.Message}");
        }

    }


    private async Task ResumeAfterWikipedia(IDialogContext context, IAwaitable<object> result)
    {
        try
        {
            var message = await result;
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            await context.PostAsync($"Failed and caught in ResumeAfterWikipedia Dialog, with Exception: {ex.Message}");
        }
        finally
        {
            context.Wait(this.MessageReceived);
        }
    }

}
```

}

I am using CallingController class to handle calls as following

```
[BotAuthentication]
// Prefix route for your calling controller
[RoutePrefix("api/calling")]
public class CallingController : ApiController
{
    public CallingController()
        : base()
    {
        CallingConversation.RegisterCallingBot(c => new JoeCallingBot(c));
    }

    // Callback route for Skype calling events.
    // Make sure to set the Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Calling.CallbackUrl in web.config
    [Route("callback")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ProcessCallingEventAsync()
    {
        return await CallingConversation.SendAsync(Request, CallRequestType.CallingEvent);
    }

    // Route for incoming call events
    [Route("call")]
    public async Task<HttpResponseMessage> ProcessIncomingCallAsync()
    {
        return await CallingConversation.SendAsync(Request, CallRequestType.IncomingCall);
    }
}
```

My JoeCallingBot class is following

```
public class JoeCallingBot : ICallingBot
{
    public ICallingBotService CallingBotService
    {
        get; private set;
    }

    private List<string> response = new List<string>();

    int silenceTimes = 0;

    bool sttFailed = false;

    public JoeCallingBot(ICallingBotService callingBotService)
    {
        if (callingBotService == null)
            throw new ArgumentNullException(nameof(callingBotService));

        this.CallingBotService = callingBotService;

        CallingBotService.OnIncomingCallReceived += OnIncomingCallReceived;
        CallingBotService.OnPlayPromptCompleted += OnPlayPromptCompleted;
        CallingBotService.OnRecordCompleted += OnRecordCompleted;
        CallingBotService.OnHangupCompleted += OnHangupCompleted;
    }

    private Task OnIncomingCallReceived(IncomingCallEvent incomingCallEvent)
    {
        var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        incomingCallEvent.ResultingWorkflow.Actions = new List<ActionBase>
            {
                new Answer { OperationId = id },
                GetRecordForText("Welcome! How can I help you?")
            };

        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }

    private ActionBase GetRecordForText(string promptText)
    {
        PlayPrompt prompt;
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(promptText))
            prompt = null;
        else
            prompt = GetPromptForText(promptText);
        var id = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();
        return new Record()
        {
            OperationId = id,
            PlayPrompt = prompt,
            MaxDurationInSeconds = 10,
            InitialSilenceTimeoutInSeconds = 5,
            MaxSilenceTimeoutInSeconds = 2,
            PlayBeep = false,
            RecordingFormat = RecordingFormat.Wav,
            StopTones = new List<char> { '#' }
        };
    }

    private Task OnPlayPromptCompleted(PlayPromptOutcomeEvent playPromptOutcomeEvent)
    {
        if (response.Count > 0)
        {
            silenceTimes = 0;
            var actionList = new List<ActionBase>();
            foreach (var res in response)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine($"Response ----- {res}");
            }
            actionList.Add(GetPromptForText(response));
            actionList.Add(GetRecordForText(string.Empty));
            playPromptOutcomeEvent.ResultingWorkflow.Actions = actionList;
            response.Clear();
        }
        else
        {
            if (sttFailed)
            {
                playPromptOutcomeEvent.ResultingWorkflow.Actions = new List<ActionBase>
                {
                    GetRecordForText("I didn't catch that, would you kindly repeat?")
                };
                sttFailed = false;
                silenceTimes = 0;
            }
            else if (silenceTimes > 2)
            {
                playPromptOutcomeEvent.ResultingWorkflow.Actions = new List<ActionBase>
                {
                    GetPromptForText("Something went wrong. Call again later."),
                    new Hangup() { OperationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() }
                };
                playPromptOutcomeEvent.ResultingWorkflow.Links = null;
                silenceTimes = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                silenceTimes++;
                playPromptOutcomeEvent.ResultingWorkflow.Actions = new List<ActionBase>
                {
                    GetSilencePrompt(2000)
                };
            }
        }
        return Task.CompletedTask;
    }

    private async Task OnRecordCompleted(RecordOutcomeEvent recordOutcomeEvent)
    {
        if (recordOutcomeEvent.RecordOutcome.Outcome == Outcome.Success)
        {
            var record = await recordOutcomeEvent.RecordedContent;
            BingSpeech bs = new BingSpeech(recordOutcomeEvent.ConversationResult, t => response.Add(t), s => sttFailed = s);
            bs.CreateDataRecoClient();
            bs.SendAudioHelper(record);
            recordOutcomeEvent.ResultingWorkflow.Actions = new List<ActionBase>
            {
                GetSilencePrompt()
            };
        }
        else
        {
            if (silenceTimes > 1)
            {
                recordOutcomeEvent.ResultingWorkflow.Actions = new List<ActionBase>
                {
                    GetPromptForText("Thank you for calling"),
                    new Hangup() { OperationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString() }
                };
                recordOutcomeEvent.ResultingWorkflow.Links = null;
                silenceTimes = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                silenceTimes++;
                recordOutcomeEvent.ResultingWorkflow.Actions = new List<ActionBase>
                {
                    GetRecordForText("I didn't catch that, would you kinly repeat?")
                };
            }
        }
    }

    private Task OnHangupCompleted(HangupOutcomeEvent hangupOutcomeEvent)
    {
        hangupOutcomeEvent.ResultingWorkflow = null;
        return Task.FromResult(true);
    }

    private static PlayPrompt GetPromptForText(string text)
    {
        var prompt = new Prompt { Value = text, Voice = VoiceGender.Female };
        return new PlayPrompt { OperationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Prompts = new List<Prompt> { prompt } };
    }

    private static PlayPrompt GetPromptForText(List<string> text)
    {
        var prompts = new List<Prompt>();
        foreach (var txt in text)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrEmpty(txt))
                prompts.Add(new Prompt { Value = txt, Voice = VoiceGender.Female });
        }
        if (prompts.Count == 0)
            return GetSilencePrompt(1000);
        return new PlayPrompt { OperationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Prompts = prompts };
    }

    private static PlayPrompt GetSilencePrompt(uint silenceLengthInMilliseconds = 3000)
    {
        var prompt = new Prompt { Value = string.Empty, Voice = VoiceGender.Female, SilenceLengthInMilliseconds = silenceLengthInMilliseconds };
        return new PlayPrompt { OperationId = Guid.NewGuid().ToString(), Prompts = new List<Prompt> { prompt } };
    }

}
```

My complete BingSpeech class is as following

```
public class BingSpeech
{
    private DataRecognitionClient dataClient;
    private Action<string> _callback;
    private ConversationResult conversationResult;
    private Action<bool> _failedCallback;

    public BingSpeech(ConversationResult conversationResult, Action<string> callback, Action<bool> failedCallback)
    {
        this.conversationResult = conversationResult;
        _callback = callback;
        _failedCallback = failedCallback;
    }

    public string DefaultLocale { get; } = "en-US";
    public string SubscriptionKey { get; } = "Bing Speech API KEY"; //Bing Speech Recognition Key
    public void CreateDataRecoClient()
    {
        this.dataClient = SpeechRecognitionServiceFactory.CreateDataClient(
            SpeechRecognitionMode.ShortPhrase,
            this.DefaultLocale,
            this.SubscriptionKey);

        this.dataClient.OnResponseReceived += this.OnDataShortPhraseResponseReceivedHandler;
    }

    public void SendAudioHelper(Stream recordedStream)
    {
        // Note for wave files, we can just send data from the file right to the server.
        // In the case you are not an audio file in wave format, and instead you have just
        // raw data (for example audio coming over bluetooth), then before sending up any 
        // audio data, you must first send up an SpeechAudioFormat descriptor to describe 
        // the layout and format of your raw audio data via DataRecognitionClient's sendAudioFormat() method.
        int bytesRead = 0;
        byte[] buffer = new byte[1024];
        try
        {
            do
            {
                // Get more Audio data to send into byte buffer.
                bytesRead = recordedStream.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);

                // Send of audio data to service. 
                this.dataClient.SendAudio(buffer, bytesRead);
            }
            while (bytesRead > 0);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            WriteLine("Exception ------------ " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            // We are done sending audio.  Final recognition results will arrive in OnResponseReceived event call.
            this.dataClient.EndAudio();
        }
    }

    private async void OnDataShortPhraseResponseReceivedHandler(object sender, SpeechResponseEventArgs e)
    {

        this.WriteLine("--- OnDataShortPhraseResponseReceivedHandler ---");
        this.WriteResponseResult(e);

        // we got the final result, so it we can end the mic reco.  No need to do this
        // for dataReco, since we already called endAudio() on it as soon as we were done
        // sending all the data.

        // Send to bot
        if (e.PhraseResponse.RecognitionStatus == RecognitionStatus.RecognitionSuccess)
        {
            await SendToBot(e.PhraseResponse.Results
                .OrderBy(k => k.Confidence)
                .FirstOrDefault());
        }
        else
        {
            _failedCallback(true);
        }
    }

    private async Task SendToBot(RecognizedPhrase recognizedPhrase)
    {
        Activity activity = new Activity()
        {
            From = new ChannelAccount { Id = conversationResult.Id },
            Conversation = new ConversationAccount { Id = conversationResult.Id },
            Recipient = new ChannelAccount { Id = "Bot" },
            ServiceUrl = "https://skype.botframework.com",
            ChannelId = "skype",
        };

        activity.Text = recognizedPhrase.DisplayText;

        using (var scope = Microsoft.Bot.Builder.Dialogs.Conversation
            .Container.BeginLifetimeScope(DialogModule.LifetimeScopeTag, Configure))
        {
            scope.Resolve<IMessageActivity>
                (TypedParameter.From((IMessageActivity)activity));
            DialogModule_MakeRoot.Register
                (scope, () => new LUISDialogClass());
            var postToBot = scope.Resolve<IPostToBot>();
            try
            {
                await postToBot.PostAsync(activity, CancellationToken.None);
            }
            catch (SerializationException ex)
            {
                Debug.WriteLine("Exception: " + ex.StackTrace);
            }

        }
    }

    private void Configure(ContainerBuilder builder)
    {
        builder.Register(c => new BotToUserSpeech(c.Resolve<IMessageActivity>(), _callback))
            .As<IBotToUser>()
            .InstancePerLifetimeScope();
    }

    private void WriteResponseResult(SpeechResponseEventArgs e)
    {
        if (e.PhraseResponse.Results.Length == 0)
        {
            this.WriteLine("No phrase response is available.");
        }
        else
        {
            this.WriteLine("********* Final n-BEST Results *********");
            for (int i = 0; i < e.PhraseResponse.Results.Length; i++)
            {
                this.WriteLine(
                    "[{0}] Confidence={1}, Text=\"{2}\"",
                    i,
                    e.PhraseResponse.Results[i].Confidence,
                    e.PhraseResponse.Results[i].DisplayText);
            }

            this.WriteLine(string.Empty);
        }
    }

    private void WriteLine(string format, params object[] args)
    {
        var formattedStr = string.Format(format, args);
        Trace.WriteLine(formattedStr);
        Debug.WriteLine(formattedStr);
    }
}
```

Flow is as following:
Call comes to CallingController class which forwards it to JoeCallingBot class which forwards it to BingSpeech class which later forwards it LUISDialog class

Using Bot.Builder version 3.3.3 solves the issue. But newer version of Bot Builder SDK is causing the issue. There is an open issue on Github :

[BotBuilder/issues : 2277](https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2277)

Comment: Hey Ehsan, would you please post a simplified example somewhere that reproduces your issue?  (Or, supply the rest of the code here.  I'm unable to reproduce your problem from what you've supplied thus far.)  Also NOTE: For users of Bot Builder v1.x the CommandDialog and LuisDialog classes have been deprecated. These classes will continue to function but developers are encouraged to upgrade to the more flexible IntentDialog class at their earliest convenience. https://docs.botframework.com/en-us/node/builder/chat/IntentDialog/

Comment: @EricDahlvang - I just added more code and stack trace. Can you please have a look and tell me what possibly be the reason behind serialization exception

Comment: Relate issue on github: https://github.com/Microsoft/BotBuilder/issues/2277

Comment: We've submitted an issue to the Autofac repository: https://github.com/autofac/Autofac/issues/852

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Upgrading Bot Builder to 3.9.x resolved the issue :)